# UIScrollView subview not always clickable

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, touch, addsubview

I'm adding subviews to an `UIScrollView`. For this question I'm simplifying the added view : `testView` it contains an `UIButton`

My Scroll View is working great, but **the touch on the buttons is not working well**.

- I can click on the first button but **only on the (approximative) 100 first pixels**.
- the scrolling is working very well.
- I cannot click on the end of the first button
- I cannot click on the other buttons

here is my code :

```
__block CGFloat scrollViewContentSize = 0;
__block CGFloat buttonRectOrigineY = 0;

[self.itemsToDisplay enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    CGRect frameTest = CGRectMake(0, buttonRectOrigineY/2, 320, 200);
    UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    testButton.frame = frameTest;
    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frameTest];
    [testView addSubview:testButton];
    [self.articleScrollView addSubview:testView];
    buttonRectOrigineY      += 200;
    scrollViewContentSize   += 200;
}];
[self.articleScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, scrollViewContentSize)];
```

here is image to understand well my problem :
[image: uiscrollview with button not touchable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaking the frame of my button and view. Here a working code if it can help anyone.

```
__block CGFloat scrollViewContentSize = 0;
__block CGFloat buttonRectOrigineY = 0;

[self.itemsToDisplay enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    CGRect frameTestButton = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 150);
    CGRect frameTestView = CGRectMake(10, buttonRectOrigineY, 300, 200);
    UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    testButton.frame = frameTestButton;
    testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frameTestView];
    if(idx == 0)
        testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    if(idx == 1)
        testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    if(idx == 2)
        testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    if(idx == 3)
        testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
    if(idx == 4)
        testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    if(idx <= 4){
        LogDebug(@"idx : %lu", (unsigned long)idx);
        [testView addSubview:testButton];
        [self.articleScrollView addSubview:testView];
        [self.articleScrollView bringSubviewToFront:testView];
        buttonRectOrigineY      += 200;
        scrollViewContentSize   += 200;
    }
}];
[self.articleScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, scrollViewContentSize)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bringSubviewToFront` to avoid the issue

```
CGRect frameTest = CGRectMake(0, buttonRectOrigineY/2, 320, 200);
UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
testButton.frame = frameTest;
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frameTest];
[testView addSubview:testButton];
[testView bringSubviewToFront:testButton];
[self.articleScrollView addSubview:testView];
[self.articleScrollView bringSubviewToFront:testView];
```

If you have issues again, apply  boarder around the button and check it the button area that visible manually.

Comment: Thank, I put some `backgroundcolor` to understand my views and button and some views where over my buttons. Thank you anyway